# laravel update not working inside login function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-7

```
// Request of email and password
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

// Checking credentials and increasing attempt value by 1
        if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            User::where('email',   $request->email)->update(['attempts' => 'attempts+1']);
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized access',
            ], 401);
        }
```

above is the method i have tried on laravel 8. the **question** is i want to increase the attempts column value by one if email is correct and password is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $this->reduceAttempt($request->email);
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized access',
        ], 401);
    }



public function reduceAttempt($email)
{

    User::where('email',  $email)->update(['attempts' => DB::raw('attempts-1')]);
    return  $email;
}
```

i have included `DB::raw('attempts-1')`

Comment: Code only answers are generally frowned upon, can you explain your change and why it solves the problem?

Comment: Done @prieber .